# last modified file date in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to retrieve the last modified date of a file on the server using node.js.

I've tried

```
file.lastModified;
```

and

```
file.lastModifiedDate;
```

both come back as undefined.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

For node v 4.0.0 and later:

```
fs.stat("/dir/file.txt", function(err, stats){
    var mtime = stats.mtime;
    console.log(mtime);
});
```

or synchronously:

```
var stats = fs.statSync("/dir/file.txt");
var mtime = stats.mtime;
console.log(mtime);
```

Comment: Why using `util.inspect()`?

Comment: It's not a language function, it must be a function that he created to validate the Date before creating.

Comment: But why? Can mtime not be passed to the Date() constructor safely?

Comment: `mtime` can safely be passed to the Date() constructor

Comment: @CarlosABS https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options Check the docs, it’s a Node.js function that returns a debugging string...

Comment: "The output of util.inspect may change at any time and should not be depended upon programmatically." This method has a fairly high risk of breakage compared to using an explicit date-parsing function.

Comment: It seems that in newer versions of Node, `stats.mtime` is already a Date object.

Comment: or via promise (must be in async function):
`var stats = await fs.promises.stat("/dir/file.txt");
var mtime = stats.mtime;
console.log(mtime);`

Answer (score 117):

You should use the stat function :

According to the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/fs.html#fs.stat) :

```
fs.stat(path, [callback])
```

> Asynchronous stat(2). The callback gets two arguments (err, stats) where stats is a fs.Stats object. It looks like this:

```
{ dev: 2049
, ino: 305352
, mode: 16877
, nlink: 12
, uid: 1000
, gid: 1000
, rdev: 0
, size: 4096
, blksize: 4096
, blocks: 8
, atime: '2009-06-29T11:11:55Z'
, mtime: '2009-06-29T11:11:40Z'
, ctime: '2009-06-29T11:11:40Z' 
}
```

As you can see, the `mtime` is the last modified time.

Comment: you can use also sync version: fs.statSync(path) returns same object.

Comment: @Sandro Munda Hi, I am uploading images using multer and I have to save each image modified date  how can I get it ?

Answer (score 14):

Here you can get the file's last modified time in seconds.

```
fs.stat("filename.json", function(err, stats){
    let seconds = (new Date().getTime() - stats.mtime) / 1000;
    console.log(`File modified ${seconds} ago`);
});
```

Outputs something like "File modified 300.9 seconds ago"

Comment: `seconds = (new Date().getTime() - new Date(stats.mtime).getTime()) / 1000;`

Answer (score 9):

Just adding what Sandro said, if you want to perform the check **as fast as possible** without having to parse a date or anything, just get a timestamp in milliseconds (number), use `mtimeMs`.

Asynchronous example:

```
require('fs').stat('package.json', (err, stat) => console.log(stat.mtimeMs));
```

Synchronous:

```
console.log(require('fs').statSync('package.json').mtimeMs);
```

Answer (score 5):

With Async/Await:

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const lastModifiedDate = (await fs.stat(filePath)).mtime;
```