# How to read list of files from directory, sorted on date modified, in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Need to read list of files from particular directory with Date modified by descending or ascending in **Node js**.

I have tried below code but could not get the solution.

```
fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    else {
                        var res = [];
                        files.forEach(function (file) {
                            if (file.split('.')[1] == "json") {
                                fs.stat(path, function (err, stats) {                                                                  

                                });
                                res.push(file.substring(0, file.length - 5));
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

stats parameter give mtime as modified time?

Is there any way to get files with modified date.

Comment: Flagged as a duplicate of [Using Node.JS, how do you get a list of files in chronological order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559685/using-node-js-how-do-you-get-a-list-of-files-in-chronological-order), hopefully can merge the two

Answer (score 75):

`mtime` gives Unix timestamp. You can easily convert to Date as,
`const date = new Date(mtime);`

And for your sorting question, you can do as following

```
var dir = 'mydir/';

fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files){
  files = files.map(function (fileName) {
    return {
      name: fileName,
      time: fs.statSync(dir + '/' + fileName).mtime.getTime()
    };
  })
  .sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.time - b.time; })
  .map(function (v) {
    return v.name; });
});
```

`files` will be an array of files in ascending order.
For descending, just replace `a.time` with `b.time`, like `b.time - a.time`

UPDATE: ES6+ version

```
const myDir = 'mydir';

const getSortedFiles = async (dir) => {
  const files = await fs.promises.readdir(dir);

  return files
    .map(fileName => ({
      name: fileName,
      time: fs.statSync(`${dir}/${fileName}`).mtime.getTime(),
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time)
    .map(file => file.name);
};

getSortedFiles(myDir)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the streams works well. But incase you do not want to use streams, you may use statsSync as follows:

```
 //import the fs
const fs = require("fs");

//list with statSync
//I added letters at the start of the files names so that the alphabetical order becomes different from the chronollogical
fs.readdir("./anville95/", (error, files) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log("Sorry lad, I was unable to read the files!");
        return;
    }
    console.log("Before sorting with the last modification time...");
    console.log(files);
    //compare each file with each and every file using their milliseconds modification time and swap if necessary
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
            //create the stats files
            var firstFileStats = fs.statSync("./anville95/" + files[i]);
            var secondFileStats = fs.statSync("./anville95/" + files[j]);
            //if files[i] comes before files[j] and files[i] modification time is older than files[j] modification time, swap them
            if(i < j && firstFileStats.mtimeMs > secondFileStats.mtimeMs) {
                var swap = files[i];
                files[i] = files[j];
                files[j] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    //At this point, the swapping is done thus I print out the results
    console.log("After sorting chronollogically with statSync().mtimeMs...");
    console.log(files);
});
```

Here are the screenshots I took of my results during its execution. Thank you for reading, happy coding.

[image: The screenshot. Thank you for reading, happy coding]

Comment: this is not optimized, as your are  doing statSync several times on same files Gurav answer is much more appropriate

Comment: Thanks @tomsoft, I guess the iterators are a better way of doing it. I'm still learning

Answer (score -1):

Use this package `npm i readdir-life`.

```js
readdirLife.oldest(dir)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score -4):

I have got the answer using sorting operation.

```
fs.stat(path, function (err, stats) {
                        res.push(file.substring(0, file.length - 5) + '&' + stats.mtime);
                    });
```

stored mtime to an array and sort that array using sorting technique in below url.

[Simple bubble sort c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768010/simple-bubble-sort-c-sharp)