# Download the highest numbered file

Tags: node.js

```
const zip = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: distURL + "/zips/" highestNumber + ".zip",
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        }
        axios(zip).then(response => {
            console.log("Downloading ZIP: " + highestNumber )
            fs.writeFileSync("./zips/" + highestNumber + ".zip", Buffer.from(response.data));
        })
```

I have this script above, it downloads a ZIP file from a server and there are ZIP files named as `0.zip`, `22.zip`, `15.zip` and on...

I wonder how can I download the highest available (200) ZIP file and save it?

I have been trying to figure this out for hours but I'm straight stuck.

Comment: Get the filenames. Get the filenames without the path and without the ".zip" extension. Parse them into integers and keep the largest one. Convert that to a string variable named "highestNumber".

Comment: But I don't know the file names and I just want to download the highest numbered ZIP file that is available. "Some" numbers before the highest one are not available.

Comment: Are they numbered in chronological order, by chance?  I.e., highest numbered file is also the latest-dated? If so, you could use something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559685/using-node-js-how-do-you-get-a-list-of-files-in-chronological-order

Comment: They just start on 1 till 20. The thing is I don't know the highest number that exists or all of the numbers.

Comment: Guys, I am downloading files from a URL or CDN that I don't own. I don't know the available numbers so there can be more than 20 available numbers but I want to get the highest one.

Comment: @brianrockson Oh, do you mean that it is a remote server (i.e. not the one your code is running on)? Then you cannot know unless the remote server provides some way of telling your code.

Comment: @brianrockson Is there a fixed list of the filenames which *could* exist? If so, start at the latest and keep trying until one is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read all files and find the highest numbers from that

```
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    //handling error
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 
    //listing all files using forEach
    let alltNumbers = new Array();
    files.forEach(function (file,index) {
        // put the file number in array and thenfind thehighest value
        let fileNumber = file.split(".zip");
        alltNumbers[index] = filefileNumber[0];
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you understood it wrong. I do NOT have access to any folder. I am downloading from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

## if the server supports file listing

you can list files and as previous answers pointed out,
figure the maximal number.

## If it don't

Most servers won't expose directory listing as it can cause a security issues.
But because you know the pattern of file you seek, you can use a "trial & error" method
by try requesting a file and check if it exist RetCode 200, or not there RetCode 404.
*You might want to terminate the connection upon STATUS reception and not complete the entire stream as it can be sllllooooowwwwww*

use it somewhat like a binary search (in order of 100)...
and narrow till you find the one that has next.

```
e.g.

// range seek phase
req 100 => there
req 1000 => not there
// Range = [100, 1000)

// binary search phase
req 550 => there  // 550 is mid point of (100, 1000)
// Range = [550, 1000)
req 775 => not there
// Range = [550, 775)
req 687 => there
...
```

> Note: this isn't a great method to design a system, you rather expose a `/log/last` route to download the last log file or a `/log/list` to list the available logs.
> (maybe provide FTP Access for the log folder?)
>
> But from a "hacking" perspective, it's a great method which is used seldomly.