# How to check if a file exists and is modified recently enough?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to implement a simple file caching mechanism with Node.js. To that end, I need to checks if a recently modified file exists under a given path. I have some code that returns the last modified time of the file following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559555/last-modified-file-date-in-node-js). How do I use the `mtime` object to check if the file is recent enough, for example, no older than 24 hours?

```
const fs = require('fs');

function have_recent_file(path)
{
    try {
        const mtime = fs.statSync(path).mtime;
        /*
         TODO: return true if the file is modified in the last 24 hours
        */
    } catch (ex) {
        return false; // file does not exist or is not accessible
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the file time in ms since the epoch with the equivalent 24 hours ago, something like this:

```
const mtimeMs = fs.statSync(path).mtimeMs;
const ago24 = new Date().getTime() - (24*3600*1000);
return mtimeMs > ago24;
```